# Positioning and flipping jQuery UI tooltips and pointers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, positioning, jquery-ui-tooltip

```
$(".box").tooltip({
    show: false,
    hide: false,
    position: {
        my: "center bottom-25",
        at: "center top",
        collision: "flipfit flip",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
            $(this).css( position );
            $("<div>")
                .addClass( "ui-tooltip-arrow" )
                .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                .appendTo( this );
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/av4je/

Everything is working as intended except right-aligned tooltips.

Is there a way to flip their pointers too?

Comment: is this what you were expecting ?http://jsfiddle.net/av4je/8/

Comment: No. Left-aligned and center-aligned tooltips work as expected in my demo. Your demo changed the behaviour for all the tooltips. What I want is that the right-aligned tooltips would display exactly like left-aligned and would be (horizontally) flipped/mirrored.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is , in the statement .addClass( feedback.horizontal ), it is actually adding the left class and hence it is aligning the arrow towards left .

Please check by changing the contents of the left class with the contents of the right class i.e.
replace contents of ".ui-tooltip-arrow.left" class by the contents of ".ui-tooltip-arrow.right"

You will get your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but if someone hits the same issue:

replace

```
.addClass(feedback.horizontal)
```

with

```
.addClass((feedback.element.left + 10 >= feedback.target.left ? 'left' : 'right'))
```

(feedback.horizontal is not reliable)